# Guardar dato del radio button en mi base de datos con mvc y Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework

Necesito con urgencia saber cómo puedo guardar los datos que se seleccionan a través del radio button de mi formulario.
Soy nueva, y es mi primer sitio web, en el cual me piden realizar una página donde se muestre un formulario para calificar el servicio de la empresa.
La tabla de la base de datos se llama "t_calificacion" las dos columnas son "id" y "calificacion". La idea es que si la persona da click en "Buena" esta se guarda en la columna como 'B', luego "Mala" como 'M' y "Regular" como 'R'.

En mi Controller tengo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Huerto_Del_valle.Data;
using Huerto_Del_valle.Models;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace Huerto_Del_valle.Controllers
{
    public class CalificacionController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<CalificacionController> _logger;
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;


        public CalificacionController(ILogger<CalificacionController> logger, ApplicationDbContext context, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _context=context;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }
        public IActionResult Calificacion(){
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Calificacion([Bind("id,calificacion")] Calificacion c)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid){
                _context.Add(c);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                 Console.WriteLine("Calificación agregada");
                return RedirectToAction("HuertodelValle");
            }
            return View(c);
        }
    }
}
```

En mi model, donde además se crea la tabla, hay:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Huerto_Del_valle.Models
{
      [Table("t_calificacion")]
    public class Calificacion
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Column("Id")]
        public int id { get; set; }

        public string calificacion{ get; set; } 

        [Required]
        public DateTime addDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Y por último este es el cshtml de mi formulario:

```
@using Huerto_Del_valle.Models
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster&family=Pacifico&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body style="background-color: #fff;">

<section style= "justify-content: center; width: 100%; text-align: center;">
  <div>
    <img width="200px" height="200px" src="/img/tick.png" alt="">
    <h1 style="color: #EDA80C; font-size: 50px; font-family: 'Lobster', cursive; margin-top: 20px;  margin-bottom: 10px;">Su compra se realizó con éxito.</h1>
    <p style="font-size: 20px; font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;">Nos contactaremos pronto contigo.</p>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: #EDA80C; width: 50%; border-radius: 20px; margin: auto;">
    <form action="" >
      <p style="font-size: 30px; color: white; text-align: center;">¿Te gustaría calificar nuestro servicio?</p>
        <label>¿Qué te pareció la experiencia?</label>
        <div style="display: flex;">
          <div style="margin: auto;">
            <img width="120px" src="/img/sad.png" alt="">
            @Html.RadioButton("calificacion", "M") Mala
          </div>
          <div style="margin: auto;">
            <img width="120px" src="/img/serious.png" alt="">
            @Html.RadioButton("calificacion", "R") Regular
          </div>
          <div style="margin: auto;">
            <img width="120px" src="/img/happy.png" alt="">
            @Html.RadioButton("calificacion", "B") Buena
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" asp-action="Calificacion" style=" padding: 10px 7px 10px 7px; color: white; background-color: #438DB1; margin: 20px; border-radius: 20px; "><b>Enviar</b></button>              
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
</body>
```

El problema es que EL RADIO BUTTON NO GUARDA EL DATO SELECCIONADO A LA BASE DE DATOS. Lo que implementé está basado en un video de youtube. Por lo tanto, sé que no está del todo bien...
Si hay una mejor forma, como por ejemplo, en lugar de radio button, sean imágenes, y al seleccionar se guarde la calificación en la base de datos... Estaría eternamente agradecida.
Espero puedan ayudarme lo más pronto posible :( Estaré atenta. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Pero que problema tenes?

Comment: No me guarda los datos del radio button en la base de datos...

Comment: Respecto a tu ultimo comentario, se puede hacer como quieras. Eso ya depende de lo que te pidan o quieras hacer. Volviendo a tu problema, tu tabla t_calificacion tiene 3 campos por como la describis.. un id, una fecha y la calificacion...  Estas usando Entity framework para guardar?

Comment: Pusiste la fecha como requerida.. pero no la mandas?

Comment: Sí, estoy usando Entity Framework, y en realidad creo que lo de la fecha no es el problema... Si conoces una manera más fácil de hacer lo que necesito, me sería de mucha ayuda...

Comment: No tengo ni idea de EF y te lo pregunte porque no lo aclaraste entre la multitud de etiquetas que pusiste (que la mayoria, no son aclaratorias de tu problema). Estas controlando por ejemplo que pasa si el model no es valido? seguiste tu codigo linea a linea a ver si guarda, a ver si tira un error?

Comment: Ya edité las etiquetas... Y bueno, no me salta ningún error al compilar... Tengo la sospecha de que el botón del formulario no detecta algún dato para enviar.

Comment: porque en todas esas etiquetas, ninguna dice el lenguaje en que estas trabajando (asp.net? aspnetcore? c#?)..  no te pregunte por errores al compilar, te pregunte si habias depurado tu metodo, o al menos le habias puesto un control de error.. si el modelo no es valido por cualquier motivo, no devolves un error. haces lo mismo que si es valido... que es nada.. no avisas si guardo o no... probaste depurarlo?

Comment: Buen punto... No lo depuré, y aún no me enseñan eso... ¿podrías decirme cómo?

Comment: eso depende la IDE que estes usando y hay tutoriales por internet para todas las ide. Ademas (y esto no lo se con certeza, no soy experto) tenes dos metodos con exactamente el mismo nombre, y no se a cual de los dos llama tu submit. Asi que todo tu trabajo viene por el lado de que depures y vuelvas aca cuando sepas el error que estas teniendo. Que puede ser que sea por el tema que pusiste la fecha obligatoria.. pero puede ser porque llamas a otro metodo.. o puede ser cualquier cosa....

Comment: Ya encontré mi problema y ya lo solucioné haha Pero gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responderme :)

Comment: @Michelle Uno puede responder su propia pregunta. Si no se trata de un error tipográfico (que te faltó un ; o que te equivocaste en el nombre de una variable, por ejemplo), y consideras que puede pasarle a más gente lo mismo que a ti, deberías completar una respuesta.